# Update using select in DB2

Tags: update, db2

I have 2 tables

```
Table A 
address_id email
12341      aba@mail.com
12342      abb@mail.com
12343      abc@mail.com
12344      abd@mail.com
12345      abe@mail.com
12346      abf@mail.com
12347      abg@mail.com
12348      abh@mail.com
12349      abi@mail.com

Table B 
address_id email
12342      xyz@mail.com
12344      xyy@mail.com
12349      xyx@mail.com
```

I want to update emails in table A with emails in Table B where the address_id matches.

I have tried the below query :

```
update TableA A 
set email=(select email from TableB B where A.address_id=B.address_id)
```

But its updating all the emails to null where the address_id is not matching in TableA.

Appreciate your help..

Comment: Just add a `where` to the update. (I am not sure how the exist syntax in DB2 is)

Answer (score 11):

An `UPDATE` without `WHERE` clause will update all the rows of the table. For those rows that don't have a matching `address_id` in table `B`, the subquery returns an empty result set, so the value is updated to `NULL`.

---

There's probably a more elegant way to do it but this should only update the matching rows:

```
update TableA A 
set email = (select email from TableB B where A.address_id = B.address_id)
where exists
      (select 1 from TableB B where A.address_id = B.address_id) ;
```

Another option is to use `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO TableA AS A
USING
  ( SELECT address_id, email
    FROM TableB
  ) AS B
  ON A.address_id = B.address_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET email = B.email ;
```

Comment: That worked for me, but it still updated all matching rows regardless of whether values had changed or not. I found that by using:

    WHEN MATCHED AND
    (A.col1 <> B.col1 or
     A.col2 <> B.col2)
    THEN

it did the trick.

Comment: It's never as easy as you would like is it! In this case my target table is a subset (columns) of the source table, and I only want to update it if any of the 12 columns have changed for any row. Updates to the target table are triggered, so I really only want to update where there are actually changes. There are reasons why it's done that way, it would take a book to explain...